# Using sqlite3_exec to do transactions in Objective-c and not having desired effect

Tags: objective-c, ios, transactions, sqlite

Top of the morning to'ya!

I'm currently developing a iOS app in Objective-c and I have a local database that I allow the user to update over the internet.
The database can change rather drastically in only a few short days and thus could all have been reduced to a few lines where before there were hundred of thousands (unlikely but still).

I'm using sqlite and trying to perform a transactional delete and not getting any errors while running the following code, but it isn't having the desired effect i.e the lines that should be deleted aren't being removed!

I have ran select queries on the db before, while and after but always find the data that should've been deleted.

Here is the code

```
@try {
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK){
        //Db exists and can be open
        sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        const char *query = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@ 
                                                          WHERE ? = '?'", table] UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &stmt, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //integer i = 0
            //PrimaryKey contains k primaryKeys
            for(int i=0; i<[primaryKey count]; i++){
                //i = j < k
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, (const char *)[parameters UTF8String]
                 , [parameters lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], SQLITE_STATIC);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, 
             (const char *)[[primaryKey objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String]
            , [[primaryKey objectAtIndex:i] lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]
            , SQLITE_STATIC);

                if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){
                    NSLog(@"Delete commit failed. Error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                    return NO;
                }
                if(sqlite3_reset(stmt)!= SQLITE_OK){
                    NSLog(@"SQL error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                    return NO;
                }
            }
            //i = k
        }
        if(sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0) != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"SQL error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

            return NO;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"SQL error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return NO;
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [exception reason]);
    return NO;
}
```

Any help or tips from those more used to using transactions in sqlite would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not checking the result of

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
```

There are extra quotes in

```
WHERE ? = '?'
```

You don't need those quotes with `sqlite3_bind_text`

I suspect you are trying to bind a column name for parameter 1. You cannot do this in SQLite. `sqlite3_prepare_v2` needs to know the column names; your query is just doing a compare of the name of the column against parameter 2.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm to input the column name with a %@. And added a check on the first sqlite3_exec.